Need to fix for loop in etherjs
hi im a newbie and i have a problem with for loops. my code is here
async function claims(epoch) {
  let epochs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    rounds = epoch - i;
    const claimable = await contract.claimable(rounds, Account);
    const refundable = await contract.refundable(rounds, Account);
    (claimable || refundable) === true ? epochs.push(rounds) : 0
    console.log(epochs);
  }
}
claims()

But when I run this function, I get the following response:
[100]
[100,99]
[100,99]
[100,99,90]
[100,99,90]
[100,99,90,86]

how can i bring only last row ?
[100,99,90,86]

Move the console.log() outside the loop if you want the total, not just what each iteration does.. Although just logging the result seems not very useful, you probably want to return the value.

Move the console.log(epochs) line outside the loop. This way, the function will finish all its checks and add all the numbers to the list before printing it. You'll then see only the final list as output.
